Can Lavaan handle multigroup multilevel SEM?
I am wondering if it is possible to run a multigroup, multilevel SEM in Lavaan.
I can run the analysis just as a multigroup and just as a multilevel, but when I try to specify both cluster and group, I get the following error:
Error in ov.names.l[[g]] : subscript out of bounds.
If I ignore level (specify one model rather than a level 1 model and a level 2 model) and specify group and cluster, it runs and provides multigroup output. It does recognize the clustering:
,
This suggests that it can recognize clusters and groups in the same analysis.
But the results it provides are identical to the multigroup analysis (broken down by group and not broken down by level, with identical parameter estimates to the multigroup model without the clustering variable).
Here is my basic syntax:
model_test <- '
level: 1
    # Regression equations at Level 1 (Within)
    Pos_A ~SQ_A + SQ_B 
    Pos_B ~ SQ_B + SQ_A
    Neg_A ~ SQ_A + SQ_B
    Neg_B ~ SQ_B + SQ_Alevel: 2
    # Regression equations at Level 2 (Between)
    Pos_A ~ SQ_A + SQ_B
    Pos_B ~ SQ_B + SQ_A
    Neg_A ~ SQ_A + SQ_B
    Neg_B ~ SQ_B + SQ_A    '

    fit_test <- sem(model_test, data = Data3, group = "Group", cluster = "CID", estimator = "ML")

Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am trying to find out if Lavaan has the functionality to run a multigroup multilevel SEM.

I think the bot was activated because the text does not contain a question.  But your subject line does, and the first line of text is clear what you are asking for.


Can Lavaan handle multigroup multilevel SEM?

Yes, but it will not be automatically triggered by using both the group= and cluster= arguments when the model= only contains level: blocks.

If I ignore level (specify one model rather than a level 1 model and a level 2 model) and specify group and cluster, it runs and provides multigroup output. It does recognize the clustering

That only works if it is a single-level model= syntax, because there are no level: blocks in the syntax.  It only returns cluster-robust SEs and tests.
To obtain multigroup, multilevel results, your syntax needs to include blocks for both levels and groups.  Furthermore, the grouping variable needs to be a Level-2 variable, so that the structure can be "levels within groups".  For example, with 2 groups:
model_test <- '
group: 1
level: 1
    # Regression equations at Level 1 (Within)
    Pos_A ~ SQ_A + SQ_B 
    Pos_B ~ SQ_B + SQ_A
    Neg_A ~ SQ_A + SQ_B
    Neg_B ~ SQ_B + SQ_A
level: 2
    # Regression equations at Level 2 (Between)
    Pos_A ~ SQ_A + SQ_B
    Pos_B ~ SQ_B + SQ_A
    Neg_A ~ SQ_A + SQ_B
    Neg_B ~ SQ_B + SQ_A

group: 2
level: 1
    # Regression equations at Level 1 (Within)
    Pos_A ~ SQ_A + SQ_B 
    Pos_B ~ SQ_B + SQ_A
    Neg_A ~ SQ_A + SQ_B
    Neg_B ~ SQ_B + SQ_A
level: 2
    # Regression equations at Level 2 (Between)
    Pos_A ~ SQ_A + SQ_B
    Pos_B ~ SQ_B + SQ_A
    Neg_A ~ SQ_A + SQ_B
    Neg_B ~ SQ_B + SQ_A    
'

If the grouping variable is a Level-1 variable, this will not work.  Groups that vary within clusters are random effects, and that requires different model specification:
https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2014.1003769

Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. The syntax is very similar to Mplus's multigroup syntax. I want to apply equality constraints in one of my groups and not the other, so I was following the Lavaan multigroup notation and using c(X,Y) to define the parameter labels for each group, but I like this approach (like Mplus's) more. Is this approach to specifying multiple groups in Lavaan documented somewhere (I was actually initially expecting it to be this set up because I was familiar with the Mplus syntax, but didn't see it as an example anywhere)?
Thanks again!

If it's exactly what you needed, then please remember to vote it up so the answer is accepted.  I don't think the multigroup-multilevel combination is documented because it just relies on the same block-syntax structure that a multilevel model needs.  But blocks also work for specifying multigroup (single-level) models.  I'll make a note to add examples to the tutorial on the website.
